# selecting a line in c by arrow keys

Tags: c, user-interface

Im trying to find out how can i make a line Selectable in c ? what i mean is for example i have 2 choices for the user to choose between like this code ( the code is just for example ):

```
printf("please select on of the following by pressing enter\n");
printf("1 - postfix\n");
printf("2 - prefix\n");

//after enter been pressed i'd check the choice.
switch (calculationType)
    {
    case postfixExpression : 
        goto :  postfixEvaluator(expr);
    case prefixExpression :
        goto : prefixEvaluator(expr);
    default:
        break;
    }
```

so i want the user to use the keyboard arrows (up and down) to select one of postfix or prefix and then by hitting Enter it go to the function i want it to go .
so how should i do such a thing in c ?

Comment: This is OS dependent, on *nixes you can take a look to [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Comment: it is system-dependent process, So it is better that you write the use OS and compiler.

Comment: @AlterMann: not really, ncurses runs with any posix-compatible subsystem, so windows NT4 and later is fine, too.

Comment: @AlterMann: see the edit to my answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, do you mean PDCurses? as far as I know you need cygwin for ncurses under Windows

Comment: @AlterMann: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#what_platforms lists win7/MinGW; probably the RXTerm that ships.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, wow, I didn't know that (W7 and MinGW) bye bye conio.h :)

Comment: If it were not strictly in C, maybe something like `dialog` might be sufficient for your needs. However I'm not sure you can integrate a call to it from C (e.g. via `system`), and then get the result back to your C program...

Comment: if i want to use windows can i use windows API's ?

Comment: the code is not implementing a menu.  it is telling the user to press 1 or 2  The code needs to use something like getchar() to actually input the value.  Then, never trust what a user inputs.  I.E. check to assure the value is actually 1 or 2 and loop back if the input is not one of those values

Answer (score 3):

With your `printf` based interaction, this is impossible, because `printf` can only use your console as means of a pipe through which it pushes characters.

What you'll need to do is use a library that can take advantage of your terminal's capabilities. The classic answer to this is `ncurses`.

**EDIT** @AlterMann pointed out `ncurses` only runs on unixes; that's kind of true, but kind of isn't. It needs a suitable Posix layer, and a compatible terminal; [ncurses FAQ entry on supported platforms](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#what_platforms) lists Windows 7 with MinGW, for example, and Cygwin completely.